# Display fragment outside Tabs

Tags: android, android-fragments, tabs

I have 3 tabs,  with fragments A B C.. Each of this fragments lauches other fragments in its heiracy, say A launches A1.. A1 launches A2. From A2 you can go back to A1 and back to A.  This all works fine, however fragments A1 and A2 are placed within the tab.. My question is, can I show fragments A1 and A2 without the tabs?

Answer (score 0):

Create a new FragmentActivity with the Fragments you want to show and start the activity

Comment: This is not a feasible approach since I want to navigate through the back stack with ease.. eg A2 - >A1->A so creating another activity to host these fragments is not an option

Comment: Why not?, pressing the back button will take you back to your tab activity with the fragment you left there

Comment: It will mean I need 6 more activities to host the tabs, I was trying avoid that.. Is there no way to hide the tabs?

Comment: I guess you could try to set visibility=gone to the tabs but I'm not sure if you will succeed

Answer (score 0):

I found what I was Looking for thanks to @commonsWare. In the second set of fragments i.e A1,B1,C1 I added the following line after onActivityCreated

```
getActivity().getActionBar().setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
```

this works fine and all fragments after the main one say A1,A2,An are rendered without the tabs. Next I added this line

```
public void onResume() {
      super.onResume();
      if(getActivity().getActionBar().getNavigationMode()==ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD){
            getActivity().getActionBar().setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
        }
}
```

This allows me to resume the fragment A say from A1 and still have it show the tabs.